# Creating overload methods

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an overload method in visual studio with the method name `getPrice()`, here is the first overload method I tried to create:

```
private double getPrice(double price)
{
        int intQty = 1;
        txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();
        double dblSalesTax = 0;
        lblSalesTax.Text = dblSalesTax.ToString(); 
        double dblPrice = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        txtPrice.Text = dblPrice.ToString("c");
}
```

However my naming of it is off or something it keeps giving me an error, not all code paths return a double.. so I'm not sure how to fix that and this first overload method is supposed to only take a single parameter called price and then it is supposed to default Qty to 1 and sales tax to 0, besides the error did I do any of that other stuff correct or is the whole thing wrong or how would I fix that? Once I get this first parameter set I think I can get the other 2 working.

EDIT

Ok I changed it a bit...

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    getPrice(double price); 
   }

private double getPrice(double price)
{
    double dblQty = 1;
    double dblSalesTax = 0;
    double dblPrice = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
    double dblTotal = (dblPrice * dblQty) *dblSalesTax;
    lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("c");
    return dblTotal; 
    //lblSalesTax.Text = dblSalesTax.ToString(); 
    //double dblPrice = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
    //txtPrice.Text = dblPrice.ToString("c");

}
```

There is what I have now, how can I use the parameter price with it and why does it error when i try to put it in the btnCalculate_Click method?

Comment: You are not using the input parameter inside the function. you can have function without parameters in this case.

Comment: Well, technically you did not create an overload method... yet. Method overloading is only possible with two or more methods.

Comment: I'm supposed to return data with it so it has to be of the double type. I'm supposed to return that price to a text Box called txtTotal which I didn't add to the code, not too sure how to do that part, can I just do return price txtTotal.Text ?

Comment: The return value of a method is returned to the caller of the method, that's why its called "return" value. Your description is very confusing. As it seems, the method should not return a double value, but you want to assign the double value to a textbox, right?

Comment: You need to study how methods work. There are tons of tutorials online. I am not sure why you are wasting your time here instead of learning how methods work, how parameters work etc.

Comment: Why do you think “it error”? Is VS showing you an error message? You need to [add that error message to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43837516/edit).

Answer (score 1):

You dont require parameter. You are not using the passed value inside function. You can return double value as given below:
`

```
private double getPrice()
    {
        int intQty = 1;
        txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();
        double dblSalesTax = 0;
        lblSalesTax.Text = dblSalesTax.ToString(); 
        double dblPrice = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        txtPrice.Text = dblPrice.ToString("c");
        return Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);

    }
```

`

Comment: I added a parameter to it now by changing the dblPrice i had to just use price since it was already in the form of a double and then I just returned price since I only need to return price because it defaults to qty 1 so price * qty is the same as just price but i still can't get the method working for the btnCalculate_Click, i tried to put getPrice(double price) but it has an error